# gensim KeydVectors dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

Im `gensims` latest version, loading trained vectors from a file is done using `KeyedVectors`, and dosent requires instantiating a new Word2Vec object. But now my code is broken because I can't use the `model.vector_size` property. What is the alternative to that? I mean something better than just `kv[kv.index2word[0]].size`.

Answer (score 8):

`kv.vector_size` still works; I'm using gensim 2.3.0, which is the latest as I write. (I am assuming `kv` is your `KeyedVectors` object.)  It appears object properties are not documented on the API page, but auto-complete suggests it, and there is no deprecated warning or anything.

Your question helped me answer my own, which was how to get the number of words: `len(kv.index2word)`